# Cannot run my docker image

Tags: docker

This is the Dockerfile I created for testing purposes.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Kapil Gupta "kpgupta98@gmail.com"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential tcl8.5
RUN apt-get install -y git

EXPOSE 9999
ENTRYPOINT ["myGit"]

WORKDIR /home
```

I ran this command for installing the image :

```
docker build -t mygit .
```

Output of `docker images` :

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mygit               latest              1474c446365f        39 minutes ago      414.5 MB
redis               latest              dc2bd412c10c        7 weeks ago         438.8 MB
ubuntu              latest              c73a085dc378        9 weeks ago         127.1 MB
```

Output of `docker run -i -t mygit:latest` :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"myGit\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n".
```

I don't understand what the error means and how to correct it. Please explain the error in your answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["myGit"]
```

You're telling it to run the command "myGit" when it runs the Dockerfile.  That program doesn't exist.  The [ENTRYPOINT reference is here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) .

If you just want a shell for your testing, you could just change it to:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```